# Does find element in selenium checkes if the tag is closed proeprly?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am using selenium method find element to check if the tag exists or not. For ex-

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//meta[@name='keywords']");
```

I am not sure if the tag is not opened or closed properly will Selenium still find the element on the web page?

Comment: It is not actually about `selenium`. Browsers, in general, are doing a good job for making an HTML well-formed.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to validate the HTML of the page, you can use the W3C Markup Validation Service. It is a SOAP-based service. Just add a reference to your project and build a request as the sample in the documentation- https://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html 
If you want to manually check it, just paste the desired URL here: https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Thanks Anton! am asked to use WebDriver.

Comment: @ForTesting You can do it as part of a webdriver test easily enough; you use webdriver to navigate to the right page, then extract the page source, submit it to the W3C markup validation API and check the results. That is a _much_ better way than writing your own code to validate the page source.

Comment: I totally agree with the above statement, this was my idea too, sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

The Selenium *only* runs element selector above DOM provided by the browser. And generally, the browser will create DOM (tree of elements) above almost any HTML - it is intentionally build to handle such cases, as not closed pair elements, wrongly formatted HTML etc. But the behavior of each browser could differ a bit.

So the answer is simply **no**. Selenium does not check for this, it will most probably find the element, because the browsers (which provide the data for the Selenium) have their heuristics how to parse HTML with even missing closing elements. So from Selenium point of view it could look like totally "valid" and unproblematic HTML.

To check HTML validity I suggest using different tools, like [W3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/) or the [HTML tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) project.

Answer (score 0):

In short: maybe, but not guaranteed. Depends on the browser.

In long: selenium's `findElements` method and suchlink don't actually check the html - they check the browser's DOM. Now browsers are pretty good at figuring out badly constructed html (missing end tags and so on), so there's a chance that it will have figured out what is wrong with the tag and included it in the DOM. If so, then selenium will find it (in the DOM); but if the browser couldn't work out what the tag was trying to say and hasn't included it, then selenium won't find it.

Comment: So basically I can't rely on Selenium totally to make sure Tag is constructed properly. I need to code it accordingly.